# Django: Generate form from dictionary

Tags: django, dictionary, django-forms

I'm currently working on a django-app where users have the option to select synonyms for a select number of words. These words are then replaced all over the website by these synonyms

these synonymes are defined as a separate model:

```
class TransportSynonyms(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(user)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This process is done in part with template tags, and as such the number of words that can be 'synonymed' is limited. For example, the following words can be replaced by synonymes:

```
'train', 'plane'.
```

And appear like so in the html template:

```
{% get_trans "train" %}
{% get_trans "plane" %}
```

I now want to give user the ability to define synonymes for themselves, without the admin view. I created a few pages using a ListView as an overview (so the users could see which words they can change) with individual buttons that led to EditViews.

However, I'm since user have no synonyms linked to them by default, the ListView appears empty. I could solve that by passing a list from the view, but that list wont have the required '.id' values and would be worthless for linking to the EditViews.

My listview currently looks like the following table:

```
Original | Synonym 
--------------------------- 
train | train (button to editview)
plane | aircraft (button to editview)
```

The buttons require an ID value

```
href="{% url 'synonym_edit'  pk=synonym.id %}"
```

I have to find a way to fill the ListView with the 'synonymable' words and provide links to a DetailView (for synonyms might not yet exist).

I thought about dropping the ListView all together and instead pass a dictionary to a form. By default both the key and the value will be the same word

```
({'train' : 'train', 'plane' : 'plane'})
```

and a form would then be generated form this dictionary, allowing users to change the value by having the dictionary value be shown as a text input.

Its a bit more limited (and more cumbersome) than my original plan, but I think this might work. Problem is that I've only really worked with modelforms before, and I am currently stuck on having the form be generated from the dictionary. Could anyone here point me to the right direction?

Regards,

Jasper

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you mean here as this is all quite vague. If the user has no synonyms, what `id` values do you need?

Comment: My appologies. I eddited my post to try to make it a bit more clear. 

But it bassicaly comes down to the fact that the EditView needs a primary key passed through the URL, otherwise it wont know which object it needs to link to.